# 99 Alero overheated due to low coolant, coolant light stays on after filling coolant

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, overheating, oldsmobile, alero

I was driving my 99 Alero and it started to overheat quickly like went from normal temp to red line in about 90 seconds. I shut the heat off and it dropped back down. Then the coolant light went on. I stopped the car in a safe spot (a few miles after overhear issue) and let it idle for a few minutes then shut it off. Let it cool down for a bit checked coolant it was very low so I filled it to fill line. Coolant light stayed on but temp is running okay (goes up to 50% and stays there)

I know little about cars and need help to see what it might be or if I can fix it myself or need to get it to a mechanic. Ex-bf recently put in new thermometer but I don't know if it was done correctly. Then starter went out mechanic fixed that and mentioned something about the coolant and bleeding something? Help please!

Answer (score 1):

The air needs to be  bled from the cooling system. There should be a bleeder valve on top of the thermostat housing. You'll want to loosen the screw on the valve and run the engine until air stops coming out of the bleeder valve, and you have a steady stream of coolant coming out. Once that's completed you'll want to let the engine cool down and check the coolant level again, topping of if needed.